# Reduce function y = 31(1.21)^x by (1.25)t-2

Tags: calculus

Reduce function $y = 31\times1.21^x$  **by**  $1.25^{t-2}$

Do I multiply $1.25^{t-2}$ by $31\times1.21^x$ to get my new function?

How would I multiply the two?

Comment: What does "reduce this by that" mean in this context?

Comment: @HenningMakholm to reduce the value of y = 31(1.21)^x by (1.25)^(t-2)

Comment: the question was you spill some coffee on the book, as the original function represents the rate of depreciation of the comic book in value, so youre reducing the rate by (1.25)^(t-2) @HenningMakholm

Comment: @Jessica. Do you mean "reduce" or "replace" ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici reduce, you are reducing the original function by the (1.25)^(t-2)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici that is what the question says, so in order to reduce it by that function, do i multiply them, or apply transformations?

Comment: If the wording is as in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566461/depreciation-of-comic-book), it’s a poorly worded question, but *reduce by* most likely means that you should subtract $1.25^{t-2}$.